# A consequence of Rank theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading a free book on Hodge theory. I am having a slight issue understanding this line: how is it true that $z_1 = \ldots = z_k = 0$. Aren't those variables the variables that are not zero by rank theorem?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But $X = F^{-1}(q)$ and $\psi(q) = 0$. This means that $\psi\circ F\circ\phi^{-1}(z_1,\dots,z_n) = (z_1,\dots,z_k,0,\dots,0) = (0,\dots,0,0,\dots,0)$ precisely when $z_1=\dots=z_k=0$, and $U\cap X$ is parametrized by $(z_{k+1},\dots,z_n)$.